# Scala: cleaning up constructor parameters

Tags: scala, parameters, constructor, garbage-collection

I am just learning Scala and am concerned about cleaning up constructor parameters.

In Java I had a class like this:

```
public class Example {
    private A a;
    private B b;

    private SelectorA aSelector;
    private SelectorB bSelector;

    public Example(SelectorA aSelector, SelectorB bSelector) {
        this.aSelector = Objects.requireNonNull(aSelector);
        this.bSelector = Objects.requireNonNull(bSelector);
    }

    public void start() {
        if (a == null) {
            a = aSelector.select();
            aSelector = null; // Removing reference.
        }

        if (b == null) {
            b = bSelector.select();
            bSelector = null; // Removing reference.
        }

        // Go on.
    }
}
```

Of course, it was more complex, with parameters and stuff. This class is supposingly a long-living one and I just wanted to make sure it doesn't hold any references it does not need.

I am about to port this class to Scala and made such class:

```
class Example(_aSelector: Selector[A], _bSelector: Selector[B]) {
    private lazy val _a = _aSelector() // Will _aSelector reference be cleared?
    private lazy val _b = _bSelector() // Will _bSelector reference be cleared?

    def start() = {
        // Use _a.
        // Use _b.
        // Go on.
    }
}
```

Again, it's going to be more complex but the idea is clear. So, the question:

Is Scala capable of detecting which constructor parameters (`_aSelector` and `_bSelector` in the example above) are no longer needed? Or do I have to explicitly clear the reference?

```
_a
_aSelector = null
_b
_bSelector = null
```

P.S. I understand that GC is the one detecting out-of-scope references but Scala compiler is the one defining variable scope therefore it's the one defining behaviour.

Comment: You don't need to assign those variables, you can have the private modifier in the constructor: `class A(private val a: String)`, this will be translated from the scala compiler into something similar to what you have in Java, can't tell you though about GC, you should see how the scala compiler compiles your code to Java and then you can get an idea.

Comment: Don't put them in constructor if you don't want them! Use a factory method instead, in idiomatic Scala you can put the factory method in companion object of your class. Then by naming it as `apply`, clients of this class can construct an instance by `Example(a, b)` and you don't need to worry about garbage references anymore!

Comment: By the way if you just want to make them private, just make them private as mentioned by @EndeNeu. But if you need them to construct your object then use a factory method in companion object.

Comment: In actual case selectors act more like filters which may or may not involve GUI actions. Factory pattern is actually one way to make it happen. I'll look into such scenario but I won't close this question as I'm still curious about the expected behaviour.

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari your suggestion doesn't cover the lazy case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `lazy val`s, you explicitly request that `_a` be initialized only the first time it is accessed. This requires to keep a reference to `_aSelector` after the end of the constructor, at least until `_a` is accessed for the first time.

However--and it surprised me--it appears scalac is smart enough to generate code that nulls out `_aSelector` after `_a` has been successfully initialized.

You can verify this with `scalac -Xprint:mixin`:

**Test.scala:**

```
class Test(factory: () => Int) {
  lazy val x = factory()
}
```

then:

```
$ scalac -Xprint:mixin Test.scala
class Test extends Object {
  @volatile private[this] var bitmap$0: Boolean = false;
  private def x$lzycompute(): Int = {
    {
      Test.this.synchronized({
        if (Test.this.bitmap$0.unary_!())
          {
            Test.this.x = Test.this.factory.apply$mcI$sp();
            Test.this.bitmap$0 = true;
            ()
          };
        scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT
      });
      Test.this.factory = null // <-- LOOK HERE
    };
    Test.this.x
  };
  <paramaccessor> private[this] val factory: Function0 = _;
  lazy private[this] var x: Int = _;
  <stable> <accessor> lazy def x(): Int = if (Test.this.bitmap$0.unary_!())
    Test.this.x$lzycompute()
  else
    Test.this.x;
  def <init>(factory: Function0): Test = {
    Test.this.factory = factory;
    Test.super.<init>();
    ()
  }
};
```

So, once `_a` has been accessed for the first time, and successfully initialized, *yes*, the reference to `_aSelector` will be released, and the GC will be able to reclaim it.

Comment: That's pretty neat. It happens here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.2/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/transform/Mixin.scala#L423

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use WeakReferences here to allow for the GC to clear down the references when they become weakly reachable, and then just change your guards to determine if they are still available?  If they aren't then instead of injecting the selectors, maybe inject a factory which knows how to create new references to them.  A sort of aged-out cache approach...